# How I can set code for particular page traffic in google analytics

Tags: analytics

I have checked in Google analytics tool for my website traffic for a particular page.

How I can set up code for particular website page traffic in Google analytic account?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Can you please elaborate?